# Run c++ code on turtlebot simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm totally a beginner in ROS & Robotics .. I have installed ROS Hydro and set up my workspace + sandbox.

then i started to create enclosure_escape package with 3 dependencies

```
$ roscd
$ cd sandbox 
$ roscreate-pkg enclosure_escape roscpp kobuki_msgs geometry_msgs
```

now I have to create my c++ code in src folder .. lets say enclosure_escape.cpp
which contains the following code ..

```
//include libraries
#include <kobuki_msgs/BumperEvent.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>

//define the bumperCallback function
void bumperCallback(const kobuki_msgs::BumperEvent bumperMessage)
{
  ROS_INFO("bumper hit. value = [%d]", bumperMessage.bumper);
}

//ROS node entry point
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "turtlebot_test_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber bumperSubscriber = n.subscribe("/mobile_base/events/bumper", 100, bumperCallback);

  ros::Publisher velocityPublisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop", 1);

  //create a Twist message to publish the velocity
     geometry_msgs::Twist velMessage;
     velMessage.linear.x = 1.0;
     velMessage.angular.z = 0.0;

  //publish the message
  velocityPublisher.publish(velMessage);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

**now the Question comes .. how to run this on turtlebot simulator?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94521/run-c++-code-on-turtlebot-simulator/) by [adelali](https://answers.ros.org/users/8146/adelali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2014-06-06**:
on your
ros::Publisher velocityPublisher = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop", 1);
line why do you specify ("cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop", 1) in your code? what is this doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To run this with a TurtleBot in simulation you just have to run it on the same network with the same ROS Master and it will communicate over ROS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0